# Can I get sameFile is true after copy in Java nio?

Tags: java, file, nio, java-io

I thought the result is `true` when Files.isSameFile invoke after fileB is copied from fileA, because fileA is same with fileB. However, the result is `false`.

```
Path pathA = Path.of("A.txt");
Path pathB = Path.of("B.txt");

Files.copy(pathA, pathB);

if(Files.isSameFile(pathA, pathB))
    System.out.println("file is same"); 
else
    System.out.println("file is not same"); // the result
```

I found that Files.isSameFile compare only String of Path.

How can I get true after copy? I want

```
Path pathA = Path.of("A.txt");
Path pathB = Path.of("B.txt");

Files.copy(pathA, pathB);

if(??) <-- I want
    System.out.println("file is same");
```

Comment: From the docs https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSameFile(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path) - “_Tests if two paths locate the same file._”. So they will never be the `true` in your case. You need to compare content - which is decidedly harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API call you need is [Files.mismatch(Path,Path)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#mismatch(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path)) which returns -1 when the byte comparison of two files is same.

```
boolean identical = Files.mismatch(pathA, pathB) == -1;
```

As covered in other comments, `Files.isSameFile` deals with cases where two paths that are different could refer to the same underlying file on the filesystem. For example if I have directory "build" and file "build.xml":

```
Path a = Path.of("build.xml");
Path b = Path.of("build/../build.xml");

Files.isSameFile(a,b)
==> true
a.equals(b)
==> false
```

It's also worth noting that - in JDK17 source code - the first step of `Files.mismatch` is `if (Files.isSameFile(a,b)) { return -1; };` which may avoid the need to open files for byte-wise comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted api. I upgraded my java version 11 to 12. and then I executed my code. The result was success.

Comment: @Carmel If you need a newer Java version than 11, then you should upgrade to Java 17. Java 12-16 are no longer supported (Java 8, 11 and 17 are "long-term support")

Answer (score 1):

> I found that Files.isSameFile compare only String of Path.

Not exactly. The [**Javadoc**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSameFile(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path)) says:

> If both Path objects are equal then this method returns true without
> checking if the file exists. If the two Path objects are associated
> with different providers then this method returns false. Otherwise,
> this method checks if both Path objects locate the same file, and
> depending on the implementation, may require to open or access both
> files.

Method **isSameFile()** doesn't compare the contents, it's meant to define whether `two paths point to the same location in the file system`.

This method will return **`true`** if both paths are identical according to the **`equals()`** method. In this case, `none of these paths need to exist` for real and comparison boils down to what you've called a comparison of strings.

If it is not the case it'll try to access these paths.
If they represent the location in the file system that, i.e. one path is a [**symbolic link**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html) that point to another path **isSameFile()** will return **`true`**.
If both of them exit but do not lead to one another it'll return `false`.

And if at least one of them is not present in the file system it'll throw an exception.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path p1 = Paths.get("C:", "a", "b", "c", "test.txt");
        Path p2 = Paths.get("C:",".", ".", ".", "FooBar", "..", "a", "b", "c", "test.txt");

        Path p3 = p1.resolveSibling(Paths.get("copy.txt")); // path that leads to another file in the same folder
        Path copy = Files.copy(p1, p3); // contents of p1 is being coped into p3, path to p3 is returned

        System.out.println("Path 'p1': " + p1);
        System.out.println("Path 'p2`: " + p2);
        System.out.println("Path 'copy': " + copy);
        System.out.println("\np1 and p2 are the same:   " + Files.isSameFile(p1, p2));
        System.out.println("p1 and copy are the same: " + Files.isSameFile(p1, copy));

//        Path p4 = Paths.get("C:", "a", "link.txt");
//        Path symbolicLink = Files.createSymbolicLink(p4, p1);
//        System.out.println("p1 and symbolicLink are the same: " + Files.isSameFile(p1, symbolicLink));
    }
```

Lines that deal with symbolic links are commented out because it cant be done in a such straightforward way. Symbolik links could introduce vulnerabilities and the system will not allow JVM to do this action. But if we assume that there is a symbolic link that points to p1 then `Files.isSameFile(p1, symbolicLink)` will return **`true`**

**output**

```
Path 'p1': C:\a\b\c\test.txt
Path 'p2`: C:\.\.\.\FooBar\..\a\b\c\test.txt
Path 'copy': C:\a\b\c\copy.txt

p1 and p2 are the same:   true
p1 and copy are the same: false
```

**Comparison of content of the files**

To `compare the actual contents` of the files `apart from Files.mismatch()` which is accessible `only` with the latest long-term support version of Java you may create your own method that looks for discrepancies between the files like that:

```
    public static boolean compareFiles(Path p1, Path p2) throws IOException {
        boolean isSameFile = true;
        try (var input1 = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(p1));
             var input2 = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(p2))) {
            byte[] buffer1 = new byte[1024];
            byte[] buffer2 = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead1 = -1;
            int bytesRead2 = -1;
            while (isSameFile  && bytesRead1 != 0 && bytesRead2 != 0) {
                bytesRead1 = input1.readNBytes(buffer1, 0, buffer1.length);
                bytesRead2 = input2.readNBytes(buffer2, 0, buffer2.length);
                if (!Arrays.equals(buffer1, buffer2)) {
                    isSameFile = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It works very well too. I think It is good in java 11 version too. by the way, isSameFile of  variable don't need. Use return insted of  it. Thank you.